# Polymorphism in Unity with mono-behaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with polymorphism in unity. I want to create a abstract base "Gun" class to represent guns in my doom-clone game. Next i want to create some children classes like "shotgun","pistol" and so on then make for example list of "Guns" when i store each children. But when i want to do this i need to derive from my base "Gun" class, and not from mono behaviour. That way i cannot store references to for example animator, or audio Source in my children scripts like Shotgun. I want the sound of shotgun to be stored inside shotgun script, so when i want to play it i just call specific object method. But without mono behaviour it seems impossible. I don't think scriptable objects solve my problem either. What should i do then?

Comment: Your base class could inherit from MonoBehavior or ScriptableObject.

Comment: I've had a similar issue and I've ended up creating my own monobehaviour, ex ("MyCustomMonobehaviour") that obviosly inherits from Monobehaviour. Then you create a "Gun" class that inherits from "MyCustomMonobehaviour" class. You can do similar for Scriptables.

Comment: @Retired Ninja but would that mean that i can now store references on my children class and add them in inspector if it inherits from Gun class?

Comment: Unity is component-based. Therefore, you can attach components to GameObjects or search for them in the scene. MonoBehaviour has the function of being attached to GameObjects. So if you inherit from MonoBehaviour and do not change any functionality of MonoBehaviour that would break this function, everything should be fine.

There is only one caveat: your scripts must be saved in a separate file with the same name as your class. Otherwise, Unity will not be able find them or to add these components to your GameObjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have

```
public abstract class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    // common members like e.g.
    // either private -> only this class has access
    // or protected -> only this class and inherited classes have accss
    // or public -> every other type has access
    [SerializeField] protected AudioSource audio;
    [SerializeField] protected Animator animator;

    // abstract methods all inheritors HAVE TO implement
    // maybe virtual methods inheritors CAN overrule or extend but don't have to
    // other common private/protected/public methods etc
    public virtual void Shoot()
    {
        // reduce one bullet
        // play your sound file etc
    }
}
```

and then each in its own file

```
public class Pistol : Gun 
{ 
    
}
```

and

```
public class Shutgun : Gun 
{ 
     
}
```